# vb.net - StreamReader hangs if there is nothing to read

Tags: vb.net, tcp, stream, streamreader

i have this code to read the TCP stream:

```
  Function checkdata() As String
    Dim Stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    sr = New StreamReader(Stream)

    Dim s As String = sr.ReadLine() <------------
    Return s
  End Function
```

Problem is that if there is no new data on the stream, the code hangs on the marked line. Why? how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the `.DataAvailable` property of a `NetworkStream`?

```
Function checkdata() As String
    Dim Stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    If Stream.DataAvailable Then
        Dim SR = New StreamReader(Stream)
        Dim s As String = SR.ReadLine()
        Return s
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```